# Function pointers in javascript using django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-views

Is this a valid function pointer code below,

In views ,

```
    def change(request):
       dict={}
       function_ptr="create()" 

        dict.update({'function_ptr' : function_ptr})
       return render_to_response('mpjt/create.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request,{'dict': dict}))
```

In create.html

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
     var a = '{{dict.function_ptr}}'

     func_ptr(a);

      function create()
     {
       alert('got respponse');
      }
     });
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Pass `function_ptr='create'` in your python code and use the following in your JavaScript:

```
var func_ptr = window[{{ dict.function_ptr }}];
```

This must be done AFTER the function create() has been defined!
If you want to do it earlier, you could do it with an anonymous function:

```
var func_ptr = function() {
    return window[{{ dict.function_ptr }}];
}
```

Comment: Can  u please explain how is it different?

Comment: window['funcname'] is the proper way to get the function pointer from a string. A string containing 'funcname' or 'funcname()' is just a plain string - not a function (pointer). And while you could execute 'funcname()' with eval() that's very dirty ("eval is evil")

Comment: Whoever downvoted it: What about a comment? It's pretty rude to downvote a correct answer without mentioning a reason.